# Problems with Access 2007 Project Form filters

Tags: ms-access, adp

I am in the process of moving several Access databases into a SQL 2008 R2 server using Access 2007 Projects as the frontends and we're running into problems when users are trying to filter data from the forms.

Example:

I have one project file setup so that the users can search customer data and I'm using a login to the server that only has "CONNECT" and "SELECT" rights so they can't change any of the data.  The only form in this project has it's record source set directly to the table, no views or queries.  If a user selects the "Customer#" and then presses the "Filter" button, selects "Text Filter" and enters a customer number they get an "Enter a valid value" error (same thing happens if they select a field on the form and right click and try to set a filter).  If the user uses the "Advanced/Filter By Form" there's no problems.

There are no other filters set on the form or in code, no input validations, just a plan form.

Anyone have any ideas where to start on debugging this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to confirm that it is a MSSQL permission issue. To check this - try the same with MSSQL user that doesn't have any permission restrictions. Then, you can use MSSQL profiler to look at what actual MSSQL statements are being sent by Access. I beleive that it is not the simple "SELECT", but it will be some system stored procedures calls (that's how Access works with MSSQL). Look at this trace and try to understand permissions that should be added. If your Access application works on the tables level, then may be it would be easier to deny update/delete instead of granting select only - not sure that it will help, but it's just an idea what you can try.